# Is it possible to load two flat files with different columns, perform calculations on the data, and then upload one data set to the database?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have two files that look sorta like this:

[image]

I need to upload the data from `File 1`. But before I do, I need to remove the quantity in `File 2` from `File 1`. In this case, the final value would be 80. But in some cases, it might be negative and I would need to show 0 instead.

Is it possible to import both files and do the calculations as needed? I would think I could use a script block, but I'm unsure if it would be possible to pull the data from the second file as I'm iterating through the first.

I probably *could* upload to a staging table and call a proc, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible. You can use `MERGE JOIN`, `DATA CONVERSION` and `DERIVED COLUMN`

File1 Input

```
Name,Quantity
A123,100
A234,40
```

File2 Input

```
Name,Quantity
A123,80
A234,80
```

DataFlow Task

[image]

`MERGE JOIN`

[image]

`Data conversion` is simply to convert Quantities to `DT_NUMERIC`

[image]

Add the below in derived column

```
[Copy of Quantity_File1] - [Copy of Quantity_File2] > 0 ? [Copy of Quantity_File1] - [Copy of Quantity_File2] : 0
```

Output

[image]

As mentioned in the comment, the sources for `MERGE JOIN` should be sorted. You can do that by either using `SORT` or In the `Advanced Properties --> Input and Output Properties`.Change `IsSorted` to `True` .Then select your `Name` column and `SortKeyPosition` to 1

Comment: Doesn't merge Join require incoming data to be sorted?

Comment: @KeithL.. It should be sorted. I forgot to add that point. Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MERGE JOIN transformation in SSIS.  And you can add a DERIVED column transformation to do the calculation after the tables have been joined.